# asp C# login problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I am looking for a way to authenticate at multiple servers at the same time. One login for multiple sites ( a.com , b.com, c.com )

All the servers are on one network. Ldap authentication

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

One way is by making cookies available across domains as described in this [article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm).

Better and more detailed article regarding ASP.NET [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOModel.aspx).

Comment: @David. Not true. Read the rest of the article.

Comment: True.  They are using a series of webservices and redirects on top of session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign on. This is what you are looking for.

There should be lot of examples on net. see one of them below

```
 http://aspalliance.com/1545
```

LDAP example:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/LDAPSSO.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have a common authentication across multiple sites?
If so, you need to share authentication cookies across multiple ASP.NET web sites. You
use the same machineKey in your web.config files.

When you have logged in to one web site, navigate to second web site in
the same browser session should identify you as logged. Put a asp:LoginName
control and you will see the user name.

For further details see [this](http://www.justskins.com/forums/forms-authentication-over-multiple-145900.html)